# Hibernate Join table with more than one condition but @WhereJoinTable not work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join

There are two tables A and B:

A(id, b_id, a_other)

B(id, b_other)

The corresponding classes of A and B is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = true)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "b_id > 0")
    private B b;

    @Column(name = "a_other")
    private Integer aOther;
} 

public class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "b_other")
    private Integer bOther;
}
```

The query what I want is like：
`select * from A left join B on A.b_id = B.id and A.b_id != 0`;

You may find the **pain point is that extra join condition  A.b_id != 0**

I attach `@WhereJoinTable(clause = "b_id > 0")` as above in class A, but it makes no sense because I find it doesn't work at all.

I change `@WhereJoinTable` to `@Where`, I find nothing change, could anyone help to finger out what's missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want A.b_id != 0, you can add below annotation

```
@Where(clause = 'b_id > 0')
```

So your code should look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
```

> ```
>     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
>     @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = true)
>     @Where(clause = 'b_id > 0')
> ```

```
    private Audience audience;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "a_other")
    private Integer aOther;
} 

public class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "b_other")
    private Integer bOther;
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: What you said works as `select * from A left join B on A.b_id = B.id where A.b_id != 0`, I'll get nothing when `A.b_id = 0`, what I want is `select * from A left join B on A.b_id = B.id and A.b_id != 0`, I'll get object A with null B and not null aOthers when `A.b_id = 0`, it's different.

Comment: However, ` @Where(clause = 'b_id > 0')` above field not work, I find no effect in hibernate SQL log.

Comment: Can you share a random example as if what you are getting.... That should work. Have you tried it after @JoinColumn statement

Comment: I tried with two examples, here is one log of them: `select a0_.id as id1_0_0_, a0_.a_other as a_other2_0_0_, a0_.b_id as b_id3_0_0_, b1_.id as id1_1_1_, b1_.b_other as b_other2_1_1_ from a a0_ left outer join b b1_ on a0_.b_id=b1_.id where a0_.id=?`, the @Where clause have no effect

Comment: Have you write Where after @JoinColumn

Comment: Sure, `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = true) @Where(clause = "b_id > 0") private B b;`